# QML touch does not work for certain elements

Tags: qt, qml, touch, qtquick2

I have a QML based application that I am running on raspberry pi and I am successfully using the qt virtual keyboard and it is working fine, so the touch events are being generated on the device screen. I am using Qt `5.9`

Now, I have a `TooButton` object which is defined as:

```
ToolButton {
    id: backButton
    contentItem: Image {
        fillMode: Image.Pad
        horizontalAlignment: Image.AlignHCenter
        verticalAlignment: Image.AlignVCenter
        source: "images/back.png"
        visible: true
    }
    onClicked: {
        onNavigateBack()
    }
}
```

This works on the Desktop but somehow no touch events are generated for this control. Is implementing the `onClicked` handler not enough?

I have another control which has the same problem. In this case, I am using the `MouseArea`. Something like:

```
Image {
        id: exitButton
        width: 24
        height: 24
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 5
        source: "images/exit.png"

        MouseArea {
            id: exitButtonMouseArea
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
    }
```

Again, this works on the Desktop but no touch events seem to be generated.

I wonder if something else needs to be done as well to enable touch for these controls?

Comment: Can you print the `height` and `width` of `contentItem` when `onClicked` slot is called

Comment: I did. It comes as `40, 40`

Comment: and same for `backButton`?

Comment: Yes, they are both at 40, 40 for width and height

Comment: Can you give `background` to `backbutton` to see if it is visible on device. Eg: `background: Rectangle {color: "red";}`

Comment: @PraveenKumar It is definitely visible as I see the image and everything.

Comment: Agreed that it is visible. My intention is to check what is the clickable area, like in this case, if we click within the area which is in "red" color, only then clicked() signal is generated.I just wanted to cross verify that both in desktop and device, clickable area is painted as "red".

Comment: I will update. My device just went down now and I need to repair that :/ I will update as soon as I have it up and running.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  Having a similar issue here and am baffled. Even a standard SwipeView doesn't work on Android (fine on desktop). Everything is visible, just no interaction. I suspect some layer is preventing/obscuring touch events, but can't figure out what that could be.